# connect to virtual machine fro windows machine

Tags: networking, browser, virtual-machine

I am try to connect windows machine to virtual machine centos basic server
in order to use Mozilla browser to open the gitlab.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that this question is being asked by a beginner to virtualization. If this is wrong, please let me know.

1) Are you attempting to administer the Gitlab server or use a gitlab server as a git repository?

If you are setting up and administering the Gitlab server: Then we then to know a few more things either about your current setup or your goals.

You didn't mention how the VM was created. Are you manually creating a GitLab server and if so how - what have you done to get to this point. That is the starting point.

The next question will have to do with the way you are user VirtualBox and thus how your Centros VM was setup to create the network interfaces ( use the hosts network ( bridge with a vSwitch )?, use the host IP ( Sharing )? )

Thus far we have:

Host OS = Window 7 ( Version ??? ), guest OS (Centos ???), and GitLab ??? with versions?

Let us ignore what I have written below and get the above questions answered.

---

Then once we have that, GitLab is administered just like all any other application: http://:

If one is on the centos VM via SSH. Then you can get the address with:

> > ipconfig
> >     or
> >     ifconfig

And check the connection with
curl :
where localhost and/or 127.0.0.1 and/or one of the ipaddresses from ipconfig are the

The port is 8080 by default.

Thus try this when you are able to ssh into the VM
curl 127.0.0.1:8080

In general, just try http==80, https=443 and http-alt=8080 for the port as a first guess.

---

TCP ports for GitLab services are already taken
By default, Unicorn listens at TCP address 127.0.0.1:8080. Nginx listens on port 80 (HTTP) and/or 443 (HTTPS) on all interfaces.

Comment: i am try to connect win7 to virtual box centos basic server that run gitlab 
i need when i enter http://127.0.0.1 in windows machine enter to gitlab in VM centos server

Comment: i am new in this pls add details how to do that.

Comment: i know ip of guest OS Centos 6.5 i can do ssh through the putty ,but my problem how to open localhost of GuestOS from the host OS (windows 7 64bit) using firefox.

Comment: @user3133212 - In a webbrowser: `code`http://localhost:80 is the normal web browser url for localhost.

Comment: @user3133212 - The :80 after the base url is called the port. I list other common ports above including the likely one for GitLab which is 8080. So try [link](http://localhost:8080)

Comment: @user3133212 - What are your settings for networking for the VirtualBox instance? (Not attached/NAT/NAT Network/Bridged Adapter/Internal Network/Host-only Adapter/Generic Driver) And how was the instance created? (vagrant?/manually?)

Comment: Bridged Adapter - This means that you are not going to use localhost. You need to determine the address of the guest VM. I assume something on your network is providing IP address. A router of some type. I would to see what IP address the router's DHCP server gives your Centos box. Or you could login to the Centos VM and use the command ifconfig in the terminal on the Centos box....